# Create a local var for each element of a table [LUA]

Tags: lua

Sorry in advance if the title of this post is misleading, I'm fairly new to Lua and I'm not sure how to go about this. I want to create a local var for each element of a table, then print it.

Since I don't speak English well and my knowledge is not very good, I will add an example to explain myself:

```
testTable = { test1 = "Test 1", test2 = "Test 2", test3 = "Wow so many test" }

for ?? in testTable do ?????? end

print(test1)
print(test3)
```

```
Output should then be:
Test 1
Wow so many test
```

I know I can use `testTable.test1` in the print, but the purpose here is to create a local var `test1`

What would be the best approach for this situation?

Comment: `local test1 = testTable.test1`

Comment: Please read the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and add some further explanation to your question. Lua bytecode doesn't even store local variable names (except as debug info), so there's no way to create them on the fly like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
testTable = { test1 = "Test 1", test2 = "Test 2", test3 = "Wow so many test" }

for k, v in pairs(testTable) do
  print(v)
end
```

In this loop variable v is local to the loop's body. If you don't want to traverse over your entire table you can simply do

```
local test1 = testTable.test1
local test3 = testTable.test3
```

Which will become a bit tedious for too many elements.

The question is more what you want to achieve doing that.

Note that your table has no order. So if you want to print them in order you have to sort the keys first.

```
local keys = {}
for k, v in pairs(testTable) do
  table.insert(keys, k)
end

table.sort(keys)

for i,v in ipairs(keys) do
  local test = testTable[v]
  print(test)
end
```

You'll need cleverer sorting if you exceed test9 but that's another topic.

Maybe consider using a sequence:

```
testTable = {"Test 1", "Test 2"}
```

Or if you're actually using these strings use a numeric for loop instead of that table.

```
for i = 1, 16 do
  print("Test " .. i)
end
```